# Url Explode for value

Tags: php

Currently I have a url thats like this,

http://website.com/type/value

I am using

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = trim($url, '/');
$array = explode('/',$url);
```

this to get the value currently but my page has Facebook like's on it and when it is clicked it adds all these extra variables. `http://website.com/type/value?fb_action_ids=1234567&fb_action_types=` and that breaks that value that I am trying to get. Is there another way to get the specific value?

Comment: Trim it off with `preg_replace('/(\?.*)$/', '', $url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that this will always be a valid URL, you can use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
list(, $value) = explode('/', parse_url($url)['path']);
```

Comment: You should note that direct access to that parse_url array element is php 5.4+

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
$array = explode('/',$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Or, this:

```
$array = explode('/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

With this, you do not need the `trim()` call or the temp var `$url` - unless you use it from something else.

The reason for two options is I don't know if `/type/value` is being passed to an `index.php` or if `value` is in fact a php file. Either way, one of the two options will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `preg_replace`

```
explode('/', preg_replace('/?.*$/', '', $url));
```